# Yosemite Spotlight on Client not index server shared folder

Tags: spotlight, server.app

I've a Mac Mini Server (Yosemite server) where is located the folder: 'Studio'.
This folder is shared in the same network.

I've a Client iMac (Yosemite) that access to that folder 'Studio' located on server.

Spotlight on Server is able to search in that folder.
Sporlight on Client is NOT able to search in that folder.

I've run on Client terminal:

```
sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/Studio
```

And have this error:

```
/Volumes/Studio:
2015-02-14 11:53:22.017 mdutil[4611:159875] mdutil disabling Spotlight: /Volumes/Studio -> kMDConfigSearchLevelOff
Error: unable to perform operation.  (-403)
    Server search enabled.
```

Any hints?

Comment: This might be a permissions problem on the server. Try Disk Utility to repair permissions and use Finder Get Info to check rights for the volume.

Comment: Yes, there was tons of permissions error on server disk but unfortunately, after repair permession, and execute the command: sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/Studio i receive the same unable to perform operation message error. Any more hints ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry. I have not seen this problem firsthand. I had a customer who was able to fix the problem and then reported: "I think the problem was with the permissions on the server. Once they were repaired, using the recovery mode, HoudahSpot is now performing normally."  
Have you tried:
sudo mdutil -i on "/Volumes/Studio"

Comment: Thanks, i've executed on client sudo mdutil -i on "/Volumes/Studio and i don't receive error message nor password. What next ? I should execute now sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/Studio

Comment: I've executed also again sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/Studio and received the same (old) error message. Btw i use Alfred on Client that points to /Studio shared network folder and it works like a charm. The odd is that Alfred relies on Spotlight, so i'm really confused why Alfred works and Spotlight no ...

Comment: Is the file serving being done over SMB or AFP? I think that the Spotlight stuff is only supported over AFP - making sure that only AFP is being served might do the trick.

Comment: Yes @j-beda thanks, 2 days ago i've simply have disabled the SMP and leave only AFP on. Now works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the Spotlight stuff is only supported over AFP - making sure that only AFP is being served should do the trick. This might be useful: [Does OS X Yosemite support spotlight on network drives?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164443/does-os-x-yosemite-support-spotlight-on-network-drives)