# Can't Spotlight search mounted server volume: Unable to perform operation. (-403) Server search enabled

Tags: macos, network, finder, spotlight, afp

I am trying to get Spotlight to search files on a AFP-mounted NAS on my home network.

Per the advice in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164443/does-os-x-yosemite-support-spotlight-on-network-drives), I run the following command to activate indexing:

```
mdutil /Volumes/name -i on
```

But this yields the error:

> Error: unable to perform operation.  (-403)
>       Server search enabled.

When running the command to show the current status, it appears as if search is already enabled.

```
mdutil /Volumes/name
```

> Server search enabled.

What can be  done to resolve this situation? I have seen that there are some other questions about the `(-403) Server search enabled` error, but I'm not sure how they would apply to my situation.

Searching the NAS in Finder works as intended, however.

Comment: Maybe a user rights problem. Have you tried to connect in AFP with the NAS user with administrator privileges?